# How to cast a null boolean from the datareader in C#?

Tags: c#, casting, boolean, datareader

I am trying to cast a null boolean from the database using this method:

```
bool? primaryFlag = reader["primaryflag"] is DBNull ? null: (bool?)reader["primaryflag"];
```

I keep getting a Specified Cast Invalid Exception. What is wrong with the method I'm using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot cast it to a `Nullable<bool>` directly. But you can use the `as` operator:

```
bool? primaryFlag = reader["primaryflag"] as bool?;
```

This works because the cast fails if the value is `DBNull.Value`, so it will correctly assign a `bool?` that is `null`.

or this  less elegant version:

```
bool? primaryFlag = null;
int colOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("primaryflag");
if(!reader.IsDBNull(colOrdinal))
    primaryFlag = reader.GetBoolean(colOrdinal);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the value in the reader is *never* a `bool?`.

Of course, if you cast to a `bool`, you'll get an error on your ternary, because there's no common type that the compiler can infer. I use a simple trick instead:

```
reader["primaryFlag"] is DBNull ? default(bool?) : (bool)reader["primaryFlag"];
```

`default(bool?)` means exactly the same thing as `null` in runtime, but it makes the null "typed", as far as the compiler is concerned.

It's also pretty handy to have this as an extension method, so you can just do something like

```
reader.GetNullable<bool>("primaryFlag")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to also cast the `null` value with `(bool?) null`.

Answer (score 0):

There a 2 logical solutions:
1 is casting the DB value to the desired task:

```
bool? primaryFlag = (bool?)reader["primaryflag"]
```

2 is more simular to you approach:

```
bool? primaryFlag = reader["primaryflag"] is DBNull ? (bool?) null: (bool)reader["primaryflag"];
```